# Access Form Duplicated Value for Continuous Forms

Tags: forms, ms-access

I'm new on Access and trying to create a database which collects some data from other users with a form. Actually I've created a mainform and users will select area from that form and it will open another form.
Second form will be input form and I get some categoric information from tables with a query.

What I'm stuck with is: my second form is a continuous form and I've added unbound text field there to get different values for categories. When I enter any value it's duplicating all of continues for values.

I've investigated internet to solve this issue, but I think I need to change some structure here that I couldn't understand how to do?
Could anyone support please?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApBemyHG8c1MhGEdCH7s38m-ncHS

Comment: I looked at db. You have macros behind main form and VBA behind subform. Why not just all VBA? I don't use macros. They just make debugging harder. Code behind subform runs when form opens. If form opens to existing record, code will modify data. Form has RecordSource that is a query with INNER JOIN - don't use INNER JOIN, in fact try binding to just one table. Should rethink your approach. Question is too broad.

Comment: You are trying to create new records based on a RecordsetClone of existing records - why? You are referencing LineNo of the existing records in LineAlan. However, since the form RecordSource is a query with INNER JOIN of 3 tables, no records return. This just gets more confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your feed backs, as I say I'm new on Access and still learning and trying several things. I make changes on form according to your feedbacks; take out macro and use VBA mostly also I have change RecordSource and bind it to a table. I have changed table relations and eliminate RecordsetClone. Now it's working great.